# regexp_substr Pattern for line splitting where separator is line break. Oracle 19c

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

How to correctly compose a mask for regexp_substr in order to get data of the form where each value is in a new line at the output? And how can I remove empty values ​​from results, `str` field? This is the case when the last value is the beginning of the line.
I do this, but this query does not return results, in `regexp_substr` I use the mask '[' || chr (10) || ']'.

```
select ft.field_id , regexp_substr(ft.validation_data,'['||chr(10)||']', 1, rownum) str 
            from mytable ft
            where ft.validation_data is not null
connect by rownum <= regexp_count(ft.validation_data,'['||chr(10)||']');
```

In the `validation_data` field of the `mytable`, the data each line looks like this:

```
-
ПДКП КА
ДКП
ДКП(Знач1/Знач2)
ПДУПА
ДУПА
<-There is a space here
```

Or

```
Знач1/Знач2
Знач3/Знач4
Знач5/Знач6
```

Each value is separated by a line break. At the beginning of each line there can be a character - or one or more spaces.
I need to get this view:

| field_id | str |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | - |
| 2 | ПДКП |
| 3 | ДКП |
| 4 | ДКП(Знач1/Знач2) |
| 5 | ДУПА |
| 6 | ДКП(Знач1/Знач2) |
| 7 | Знач1/Знач2 |

etc

Comment: can you also add original table contents ?

Comment: Are you sure about the returning result. eg. `ПДУПА` is missing, `ДКП(Знач1/Знач2)` returns twice, and do you really need to return individually `ДКП(Знач1/Знач2)` and `Знач1/Знач2` too ?

Comment: The simplest way is just to copy a content between two lines and paste it into regex. Or check its internal representation (to see if it is a `cr` or `lf` or both) with `dump(<your newline>, 16)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on the title and the `CHR(10)` character used, the expected result set seems wrong. Since you just want to split the strings by line feed character, no need duplicates, no need to extract the substring inside parentheses...

I presume that there is an `id` column coming from the table, and `field_id` column which is intended to be generated sequentially through use of `rownum`. But, the query will fail to yield decent results if `rownum` pseudocolumn is used to replace the value of `field_id` whenever the table has more than one rows. Then replace it with `level` keyword.

Considering all those facts, you can convert your query to the following one

```sql
 SELECT id, level AS field_id,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(validation_data, '[^'||CHR(10)||']+', 1, level) AS str
   FROM mytable 
CONNECT BY level <= REGEXP_COUNT(validation_data, CHR(10))+1
    AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL
    AND PRIOR id = id
```

or alternatively

```sql
 SELECT id, column_value AS field_id,
        REGEXP_SUBSTR(validation_data, '[^'||CHR(10)||']+', 1, column_value) AS str
   FROM mytable,
        TABLE(CAST(MULTISET(SELECT level
                              FROM dual 
                           CONNECT BY level <= 
                     REGEXP_COUNT(validation_data,CHR(10))+1) AS sys.odcivarchar2list ))
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=89d461ad6856c23bb4b655a0a8cd733f)</kbd>

**Edit** : if you want to get rid of the generated rows with whitespaces, then
add

- ```sql
  AND REGEXP_SUBSTR(RTRIM(validation_data), '[^'||CHR(10)||']+', 1,level) IS NOT NULL
  ```

  to the first,

and

- ```sql
  WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(RTRIM(validation_data), '[^'||CHR(10)||']+', 1,column_value) IS NOT NULL
  ```

  to the second queries.

Comment: Thank you. Your answer is the most appropriate and complete for me.

Comment: How can I remove empty values ​​from results, `str` field?
This is the case when the last value is the beginning of the line.

Comment: @Ambasador can you edit the question with the case exactly you want to know about?

Comment: I edited the question. In the example with data, I indicated where I have spaces

Comment: Thank you very much for your answers. In theory, now, at the first request, I have to ask what `AND PRIOR SYS_GUID() IS NOT NULL` is used for
, but no, I figured it out myself)

Comment: @Ambasador The `PRIOR` is used in order to refer to the parent row within a hierarchical query, `SYS_GUID()` is used to generate a globally unique identifier(made up of 16 bytes). eg both are used to distinguish the records by generating individual identifications per each of them.

Comment: @ Barbaros Özhan where can I read in detail about hierarchical queries in oracle?

Comment: Hi @Ambasador , you can check out [link1](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Query-Operators.html#GUID-4CC13EEB-846A-4254-93FC-E91E678BD302), [link2](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Queries.html#GUID-0118DF1D-B9A9-41EB-8556-C6E7D6A5A84E), and [link3](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/Hierarchical-Query-Pseudocolumns.html#GUID-2F2FBA6F-2FD1-47D6-A74F-DB4B31E4D400)

Answer (score 1):

If your values do not contain whitespaces inside you can simply use negated whitespace class

```sql
select rownum, regexp_substr(tt, '\S+', 1, rownum)
from (
select '-
ПДКП
ДКП
ДКП(Знач1/Знач2)
ПДУПА
ДУПА' tt from dual
)
connect by level <= regexp_count(tt, '\S+');
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=bd6c0270ce753da4033e79d4bd5b18c3

If can - use `'[^'||chr(13)||chr(10)||']+'`

Comment: If the value contains a space, for example, the `ПДКП КА`, then `КА` will be a new line, but it must be in one line `ПДКП КА`

Answer (score 1):

Or this:

```
with mytable as (
select 1 field_id,
'1asdasdad5
 2asdasd
3ФЫВФЫВ' validation_data
from dual
)
select ft.field_id, regexp_substr(ft.validation_data, '[^'||chr(10)||']+',1,level) str
from mytable ft
where ft.validation_data is not null
connect by rownum <= regexp_count(ft.validation_data, chr(10))+1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).